# How to keep track of a timer or alarm or set a trackable timer in C

Tags: c, timer, pthreads, signals, mutex

```
void alarm_handler(int signum){
  printf("Buzz Buzz Buzz\n");

  //set a new alarm for 1 second
  alarm(1);
}

main()
 {
  //set up alarm handler
  signal(SIGALRM, alarm_handler);
  //schedule the first alarm
  alarm(1);
  //pause in a loop
  while(1)
  {
    pause();
  }
}
```

I have this code that prints out "buzz buzz buzz"
my question is ...is there anyway to keep track of the seconds for the alarm.. lets that i set alarm to alarm(5).

what I would like to do is keep track of that 5...
since it will print every 5 seconds..

on the 5th second the alarm will go off and another function can be called changing the global variable to 5 then back to 0...

AM i thinking of this wrong... am i implementing this idea wrong?..I have looked at timers but im not quite sure how to set a timer AND keep track of the timer...

my ultimate task is to print something every 5 seconds.....but most importantly KEEP track of when the alarm went off.. I would use a global variable set it to 5 in that second then set it back to zero..

any ideas..comments....code...push in the direction is MUCH appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: `printf()` is not async-safe.

Answer (score 1):

Set the alarm to 1 second and do this  5 times in a row?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>

volatile sig_atomic_t secs_to_alarm;
unsigned int secs_to_track;

void setalarm(unsigned int);


void alarm_handler(int signum) {
  write(1, ".", 1); /* Writes a dot to the console every secs_to_track seconds. */
  --secs_to_alarm;

  if (secs_to_alarm)
  {
    setalarm(secs_to_track);
  }
}

void setalarm(unsigned int secs)
{
  signal(SIGALRM, alarm_handler);
  alarm(secs);
}

int main(void)
{
  secs_to_alarm = 5;
  secs_to_track = 1;

  setalarm(sec_to_track);

  while (secs_to_alarm)
  {
    pause(); /* Returns on each signal. */
  }

  printf("\nbuzz, buzz\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest way to measure time in 'C' is with the ['C' time functions](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/)

You can use time() to fetch the start time, then call time() again the get the current time and use difftime(now-current) to get the difference.

Your concept of using a global variable to keep track of the counts seems sound.